# Can you help me to understand please to this: Six-deep, for nine miles - This is my question, I am not sure about the meaning

Tags: meaning

What does this expression mean, please: Six-deep, for nine miles. The context with the previous sentence is: So they bring the coffin out, and that's the first glimpse of the boy from Twinbrook.
Thank you.

Comment: We could use more context. Who is the boy from Twinbrook. Is he in the coffin? Have you looked up the phrase six-deep in a dictionary?

Comment: We need much more context, as mdewey said. Please post the entire paragraph, and say where you heard this: a novel, a movie, a comic book, a conversation in real life...

Comment: The man in the coffin is a hero Bobby Sands. The boys came to Belfast to see his funeral. and this is their first glimpse. In the dictionary i have just found deep six, not six-deep. The source is the page 91/the book Ferryman. By the way, most of my questions are from this book these days, I want to finish the reading with the proper understanding.

Comment: Bobby Sands is a hero to some people, and not to others.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information from your comment, as well as **the entire paragraph containing the sentence you are asking about**.

Comment: Of course, BS is hero for the boys in the book, not in general...and the first part of the paragraph is: So they bring the coffin out, and that's the first glimpse of the boy from Twinbrook. Six-deep, for nine miles. We crawl our way to front. And you can see it coming. This black car. With Bobby in the back, draped in the tricolour. / Is this enough to understand better now? I

Comment: *Please [edit your post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/285582/edit) to include that information.*

Answer (score 4):

> [**deep**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deep#English), adjective
> 1.3 In a (specified) number of rows or layers
> *a crowd three **deep** along the funeral procession*

Bobby Sands (who joined the Provisional IRA while living in Twinbrook, Belfast) died in HM Prison Maze and was buried in Milltown Cemetery, nine miles away. [Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Sands#Death) that "over 100,000 people lined the route to his funeral." So the meaning is exactly that of the example sentence above: there were people standing along the road for nine miles waiting to see the car containing his body, and the people were *six deep* for those nine miles, meaning there was a row of people right up next to the road and behind those people at the front were five more rows of people.

*The Ferryman* is a play; the writing style is rather disjointed and ungrammatical, being a direct transcription of speech rather than a properly edited paragraph. You should not use dialog in a play or movie to inform your knowledge of English grammar, though you may use it for examples of idiomatic speech, if you are careful. "Six-deep, for nine miles" is not a complete sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand clearly now.

Comment: Interesting. Before reading your answer I was sure that "six deep" in any context involving a coffin must mean "six _feet_ deep," the customary depth of a grave... I couldn't figure out the nine miles though!